# Pass a var to external jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, external

How can I write

```
 var menu = $('.something');
```

and use it in an external .js file like so:

```
 $(menu).attr("class", "active");
```

I have also tried declaring the external js file after the inline code and it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you define `menu` before you import the external js file that references it, I don't see why it wouldn't work.  Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    menu = $('.something');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fileThatReferencesMenu.js"></script>
```

Give that a try.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the `var` keyword. This will render the variable global.

It is not a very good idea, though; It messes up your global namespace (and can thus create problems if you have multiple javascript files from different origins messing up the global namespace and overriding each other's variables).

A cleaner solution would be setting up a global object with a very unique name, and then adding properties to it. For example:

```
MyProject = {};
MyProject.menu = $(".something");
```

Then somewhere else:

```
$(MyProject.menu).attr("class", "active");
```

Comment: +1 good tip, too much global var advice floating around on SO!!